# Can I install Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials on 1 VM and 1 Physical Server?

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2

Anyone with experience with this, can I do this to create a secondary backup Active Directory Domain Controller?

We only have 1 Server, and I hear it's best to have at least (2) Active Directory Domain Controllers in case the Primary goes down.

If I can install WS2012RE on 1 VM (spare pc on the network) and 1 Physical (primary SERVER), is this the purpose of allowing that extra 1 VM?  Or is it meant for something else?

thank you.

Comment: I think this is a licensing question and even though it has an accepted answer, licensing is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Windows Server 2012 R2 Licensing Datasheet](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/9/F39124F7-0177-463C-8A08-582463F96C9D/Windows_Server_2012_R2_Licensing_Datasheet.pdf)

> When a customer is running all allowed virtual instances, the physical
>   instance may only be used to manage and service the virtual instances.

So no you can't do what you suggest.

Also it wouldn't be a great idea anyway. You need 2 for resilience but if the physical host had problems it would bring down the VM too.

Comment: Ok, thank you James.  I'll keep looking for some tutorials and videos on secondary DC's.  I am setting up our first small business server and still learning about everything.  We don't need anything complex, but I do understand the importance of more than one DC.  What is the purpose of the extra 1 VM license with Essentials?  Is it simultaneous or either physical or VM only?

Comment: Yup virtualising even on a one to one basis makes it much easier to replace hardware, backup, etc. And from MS point of view tempt you to scale up after you see the benefit of it.